# Is there a more efficient way to assign a spin button to a cell?

Tags: excel

Currently I am working on a spreadsheet that has over 100 cells and I need to assign each cell its own spin button. Is there an easier way/shortcut to assign a button to a cell other than going through format control?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to assign a spin button to over 100 cells - what is the use case for that??? If so you can place them with VBA

Answer (score 0):

You might not need 100 spinbuttons. You just need one that changes accordingly to your need. Take a look to this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngSpinned As Range
    Dim ObjSpinner As Object
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngSpinned = Range("F:F") '< CHANGE THIS SETTING ACCORDINGLY TO YOUR NEED
    Set ObjSpinner = ActiveSheet.Spinners(1) '< CHANGE THIS SETTING ACCORDINGLY TO YOUR NEED
    
    'Checking if the active cell is within RngSpinned.
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, RngSpinned) Is Nothing Then
        
        'If the active cell is within RngSpinned, ObjSpinner is changed accordingly.
        With ObjSpinner
            .Visible = True
            .LinkedCell = ""
            .Value = ActiveCell.Value
            .Top = ActiveCell.Top
            .Left = ActiveCell.Left + ActiveCell.Width
            .LinkedCell = ActiveCell.Address
        End With
    Else
        
        'If the active cell isn't within RngSpinned, ObjSpinner is changed accordingly.
        ObjSpinner.Visible = False
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

It is meant for the module of the sheet you need the spinbuttons in and it assumes there is already a spinbutton (form object) in the sheet. Anytime you change the selected range and if the active cell falls within the specified range, the spinbutton is made visible, linked to the active cell and moved right next to the active cell. Therefore in order to change the value via the spinbutton, the user just have to single-click on the cell and the spinbutton will appear ready to change the value.